# Advice needed to full text searching on mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, full-text-search, mongoid

I've a mongoid [embedded one to many](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-n.html) model on Rails 3.1, to full text search within. I neet something very light and simple to deploy on heroku too, without having to pay for add-ons, initially.

All heroku Full-Text Search add-on currently, seem to have just paying plans (which is no good to start with), see Flying Sphinx and Websolr.

I need advice on a good solution (a ruby gem deployable on heroku) to start with and than to scale to other cloud services eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe MongoDB's core functionalities are enough for your needs:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo

There are two more possibilities that come into my mind:

1) you can use this gem:
https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search

2) you can use elasticsearch (http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and use the following gem:
https://github.com/karmi/tire

However, you couldnt use this solution with heroku only, you would have to setup your own server, for which in the case you want to use heroku, EC2 would be recommendable

Answer (score 1):

We were using the sunspot_mongo gem with solr on Mongoid 2.4.

But after upgrading to Mongoid 3, support for sunspot seems to not be there.  So we're investigating a move to elasticsearch with the `tire` gem.  There are some new offerings in the "search as a service space" for elasticsearch, but they don't seem quite production ready yet, so hoping that changes quickly.

Hope it helps!